# duplicate a single file to a list of files

Tags: zsh, duplicate, expansion

I'd like to know if it is possible to duplicate a single file to multiple files with a different list of arguments.
I have a generic image and I need to make multiple copies of it adding a different country extension to each copy.

I tried optimistically:

```
cp -r centre-stage-synopsis.jpg centre-stage-synopsis-{en_US,fr_FR,de_DE,da_DK,ru_RU,pt_BR,ro_RO,hu_HU,el_GR,it_IT}.jpg
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this in one go?

Cheers

Comment: On a side-note: Why do you want to keep so many copies of a single image? Wouldn't symlinks be better?

Comment: It's a bit of a contrived example. I need various copy of the same image to be used wit site locales. Normally images would be different, but on this occasion they are the same. Just the system needs them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if `zsh` allows this, so please feel free to smack me if the syntax is significantly off that you can't figure out how to translate this.

I am going to post a code fragment that should do what you want from either the `sh`, `dash`, or `bash` shells (basically anything from the Bourne family).

```
for i in en_US fr_FR de_DE da_DK ru_RU pt_BR ro_RO hu_HU el_GR it_IT; do cp -r centre-stage-synopsis.jpg centre-stage-synopsis-$i.jpg; done
```

Good luck, and as I said, smack me if `zsh` doesn't like it. :)

Comment: This works just fine in `zsh`. The `-r` switch is obsolete though.

Comment: I wasn't sure why the OP was insisting on the `-r` flag myself, but I figured I'd just blindly copy the structure/contents of his example into a proper `for` loop so that he could see what I did without me throwing him a curveball. He should be able to compare his ill-fated incantation with mine and see exactly what I did with his original code.

Comment: I'm quite certain it was parts of the "optimistic attempt" to expand the insides of the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `multios` and `brace_expand` enabled (they should be on by default) you can do it with `cat`:

```
cat centre-stage-synopsis.jpg \
  >centre-stage-{en_US,fr_FR,de_DE,da_DK,ru_RU,pt_BR,ro_RO,hu_HU,el_GR,it_IT}.jpg
```

Comment: I love you people!!!